# How to determine if a category is empty?

Tags: theme-development

Is there an existing function or call in which you can pass a category id to determine if the category has child posts?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The [get_term() function](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_term) accepts a term id and a taxonomy slug. It returns an object that contains a "count" for that term.

```
$obj_term = get_term(123, 'your-taxonomy-slug');
echo $term->count;
```

I'm not aware of any utility function that *just* counts posts in a particular category.

Comment: Thanks! I also thought about using $obj= get_posts('category=n'); if($obj) {//has child!}. Is one any more expensive than the other?

Comment: @Scott B - I think get_term() is probably faster. They both run DB queries, but get_posts() does it by initiating a new wp_query object and running the query method, which runs all kinds of logic and seems pretty roundabout for the info you're trying to get. If you want the fastest option, you might look at rolling your own utility function? It'd be pretty trivial to just run a COUNT query, I'd think. I'm actually pretty surprised there isn't a function for this in core!

Comment: That works perfectly fine. I've got a "Related Posts" list at the bottom of my category landing pages, but since I allow the option of listing empty categories, I'm wrapping the div that holds the link list in this wrapper to check for child posts.